# Column not existing even it exists in the database

Tags: mysql

I'm working on these query but every time I run it it displays error

> #1054 - Unknown column 'gen_cityname' in 'where clause' although the column is there in the table

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT bgycode, scc_bgyscoretotal 
        FROM (
                SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS bgycode, 
                    scc_bgyscoretotal,id
                FROM bgyprofile
                  ORDER BY scc_bgyscoretotal DESC
                ) as result 
         WHERE gen_cityname=XXXXXX;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the complete text of the error message.

Comment: Also show the schema of the table(s) including indexes

Comment: One thing that is obvious right off is the column in your where clause isn't in the select of your sub-query. So of course you will get that error.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out will try to edit this thank you

Answer (score 0):

The column gen_cityname is used in the where clause but it is not found in the result table.Put gen_cityname in the select as shown below.

```
 SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS bgycode, 
                scc_bgyscoretotal,
                 id,
                 gen_cityname
            FROM bgyprofile
              ORDER BY scc_bgyscoretotal DESC
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out will try to edit this thank you